# Get Min() Value From Int Array

Tags: c#, arrays, min

I am creating an int array by using the below syntax

```
int start = Math.Min(Convert.ToInt32(FirstNum), Convert.ToInt32(SecondNum));
int end = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(FirstNum), Convert.ToInt32(SecondNum));
end = end + 1;
int[] ang = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();
foreach (int a in ang) {int first = a.Min(); }
```

However I have a compile error of

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Min' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.Min(IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'

What is the proper way to get the MIN() value from the array of ints?

Comment: @Vanna - good catch!  I am needing to check the array not the individual item from the array.  I also  need to set it to int first == a.Min();

Comment: You do not need the loop. Use just `int first = ang.Min();` and get rid of the loop.

Comment: Since the elements are already in ascending order, `ang[0]` is the minimum element.

Comment: @Vanna, post this as an answer.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int start = Math.Min(Convert.ToInt32(FirstNum), Convert.ToInt32(SecondNum));
int end = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(FirstNum), Convert.ToInt32(SecondNum));
end = end + 1;
int[] ang = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();

var minimumValue = ang.Min();
```